# subsector erase would increase endurance of flash memory more than whole-sector erase?

Tags: flash-memory

I'm planning to use Spansion (now Cypress) S25FL032P flash memory. ( datasheet : http://www.cypress.com/file/196861/download )

On the datasheet, it says,

>  Memory architecture
>
> – Uniform 64 KB sectors
>
> – Top or bottom parameter block (Two 64-KB sectors (top or
>
> bottom) broken down into sixteen 4-KB sub-sectors each)
>
> – 256-byte page size
>
> ...
>
>  Erase
>
> – Bulk erase function
>
> – Sector erase (SE) command (D8h) for 64 KB sectors
>
> – Sub-sector erase (P4E) command (20h) for 4 KB sectors
>
> – Sub-sector erase (P8E) command (40h) for 8 KB sectors

So, it can perform erase operation on 1. chip, 2. 64k sector, 3. 8k sector, 4k sector level.

**My question is, In both cases equivalently consume single P/E cycle on the perspective of 64kb sector?**

1. **Single command for 64kb sector erase.**
2. **16 commands for 64kb sector erase using 4k sector erase command (P4E)**

**Otherwise, second method consumes 16x P/E cycle?**

I'm asking this because I want to issue erase command on as small as possible size while maximizing cell endurance as long as possible.

Comment: Note that the 4/8K sub-sector erase commands only work on the two special parameter sectors, NOT the entire chip.  Even if there was some endurance benefit to using the smaller erase sizes (which seems rather unlikely to me), you're going to have to erase 64K at a time for most of the chip.  It would probably be a lot simpler, and less error-prone, to use only the 64K size, rather than have special-case code that's used only 3% of the time.

Comment: Oops, I confused it is able to use 4k/8k sector access for all memory area. It is written on the datasheet 4k/8k access is only possible for small amount of area (maybe around 3% as you wrote) Thanks!